# Returning webSITE links Python Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using Python 3.5 with beautifulsoup (bs4) and urllib. The code I will append returns all the links for ONE page.

How do I loop this so it runs across all pages in the website, using the links found on each page to dictate which pages are to be scraped next. As I don't know how many hops I need to go.

I have tried looping it of course, but it never stops as pages contain links to pages I have already scanned. I have tried creating sets of the links I have scanned putting in IF not in set ... but again it just runs forever.

```
import bs4
import re
import urllib.request

website = 'http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Skyrim'

req = urllib.request.Request(website)

with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    the_page = response.read()#store web page html

dSite = bs4.BeautifulSoup(the_page, "html.parser")

links = []

for link in dSite.find_all('a'):#grab all links on page
    links.append(link.get('href'))

siteOnly = re.split('/', website)

validLinks = set()

for item in links:
    if re.search('^/' +siteOnly[3] + '/', str(item)):#filter links to local website
        newLink = 'http://' + str(siteOnly[2]) + str(item)
        validLinks.add(newLink)

print(validLinks)
```

Comment: What is your actual goal? Visiting every page on a website, especially a wiki, _will_ take forever, there are just too many pages. This is indicative of a larger problem/misunderstanding.

Comment: The script I wrote already does it... and yeah, it takes an hour or two. My script runs, and it actually will find all the links (makes a text document about 200KB in size of just links. However, it stops finding new ones...but wont stop. 

I am struggling to write a check for when it runs out of NEW links to stop.

Answer (score 0):

```
import bs4, requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin

base_url = 'http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Skyrim'
response = requests.get(base_url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
local_a_tags = soup.select('a[href^="/wiki/"]')
links = [a['href']for a in local_a_tags]
full_links = [urljoin(base_url, link) for link in links]
print (full_links)
```

out:

```
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_Wiki
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Portal:Online
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Quests_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Quest_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Aldmeri_Dominion_Quests
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Daggerfall_Covenant_Quests
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ebonheart_Pact_Quests
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Online:_Side_Quests
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Factions_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Aldmeri_Dominion_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Daggerfall_Covenant
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ebonheart_Pact
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Classes_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragonknight
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Sorcerer_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Nightblade_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Templar
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Races_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Altmer_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Argonian_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Bosmer_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Breton_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dunmer_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Khajiit_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Nord_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Orsimer_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Redguard_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Locations_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Regions_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Online:_Realms
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Online:_Cities
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Online:_Dungeons
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Online:_Dark_Anchors
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Wayshrines_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Online:_Unmarked_Locations
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Combat_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Skills_(Online)
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Skills
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Synergy
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Finesse
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Add-ons
```

First, use requests instead of urllib.

Than, use Beautifulsoup CSS selector can to filter the href base on the start, you can refer the [document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to learn more.

Finally, use urljoin to convert relative url to absoulte url

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urljoin
>>> urljoin('http://www.cwi.nl/%7Eguido/Python.html', 'FAQ.html')
'http://www.cwi.nl/%7Eguido/FAQ.html'
```

Comment: Thanks for this. While not answering my question necessarily, you gave me some solid tips on how to clean up my code, and in the process led me to discover a solution.